# PTVS Django Data Base Migration

Tags: django, ptvs

Im testing Python Tools For Visual Studio, I create a django project, make a SyncDB and install django admin with no problems, but now Im trying to make Data Base migration like: [Django 1.7 Migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/). the point is that i cant figuer out how to do that. I serched in google and find this: [How to run django database migrations with PTVS?](https://pytools.codeplex.com/discussions/570799). So the migration command is not wraped. I tried using Windows Command Prompt and install C:\Python34\;C:\Python34\Scripts; PATHS but when i type a django command like `python manage.py runserver` appears `No module named 'django'`. It seems that i am not pointing to my django project virtual env, but i dont know how to do that.

Execute command in my django app env path does not work neither.

Image:

[image]

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before using of virtual env you should activate it.  Execute `env\activate` or `env\bin\activate`.  Not a windows guy so I'm not sure which path virtualenv uses on Windows :-)

Comment: Path: [env\Scripts\activate] works, now (env) appears in console but with the same result "No module named django". I cheked again and in my virtual env django 1.7.3 is installed

Comment: How did you install django into the virtualenv?  You should call `activate` first and then `pip install django`.

Comment: Removing and re-creating virtual env solve the issue, thanks @catavaran you give me the hint to solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

You have to activate virtualenv. Go to `env/Scripts` directory and run `activate.bat`. Then go to your main project directory and try again `python manage.py runserver`. If you still see `No module named 'django'` make sure that django is installed in this environment try `pip install django`.